# How do I create a Lightroom preset that will correct lens vignetting but not distortion?

Tags: lightroom, presets

I am trying to create a Develop Preset that will do the following things:

1. Automatically apply the right lens profile (as if you had checked “Enable Profile Corrections”).
2. Correct the vignetting caused by the lens.
3. Leave in any distortion caused by the lens.

I tried to create a preset by checking the “Enable Profile Corrections” box, setting “Distortion Amount” to 0, and leaving “Vignetting Amount” at its default value of 100. Then I created a Develop Preset with the following settings:

[image: Lightroom’s “New Develop Preset” dialog, showing that the “Lens Distortion” and “Lens Vignetting” checkboxes have been checked.]

This preset applies the distortion and vignetting settings I want but it prevents Lightroom from automatically choosing the right lens profile: it always applies whatever lens profile was in effect for the original image!

(I tried unchecking “Lens Profile Corrections” in the “New Develop Preset” dialog but when I apply the resulting preset to an image, nothing changes because the “Enable Lens Corrections” checkbox is left unchecked.)

How can I create a Develop Preset—with Lightroom itself or by mucking around in a text editor—that will fix lens vignetting but still intelligently apply the right lens profile?

Answer (score 1):

Using a lens profile corrects very little distortion.  for example perspective distortion stays in the picture.  I think you want the profile to detect the lens used but keep the distortion and correct the vignetting.

In Lens Correction, Profile tab > Enable Profile corrections but adjust the Distortion setting to zero.

Click on the Manual tab and set the Vignetting as desired.  If further adjustment is needed, go to Effects and use the Post-Crop vignetting adjustment which is much stronger.   Then save this preset with only the Lens correction and Effects and Process boxes checked
[image: LR vignette correction only preset]

Comment: Perspective distortion isn't a function of a lens that can be corrected. Lens distortions that are corrected include issues that are particular to a specific lens, such as barrel or pincushion distortion, or mustache distortion.

Comment: This doesn’t work, unfortunately. When I apply this preset to a photo taken with a different lens, Lightroom applies the profile of the original lens instead of intelligently deciding which profile to use. (When I open the preset file in a text editor I can see that the name of the original lens is baked in.)